grouped barchart column positioning in ggplot (plotnine) with position_dodge2 in case of missing observation
I have a grouped barchart, with 2 groups. If in a case there are no observations for a particular column, the other of the group is centered. I can't find a way to circumvent this. I would like there to simply be a missing space for column of "height 0" instead of the remaining being centered.
Current visual
Desired visual
import plotnine as pn
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("starwars.csv")  # https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/main/data-raw/starwars.csv
hw = data["homeworld"].value_counts().head(6)
data = data.merge(hw, left_on="homeworld", right_on="homeworld")

# Local data adjustments
data = data.dropna(subset=["gender"])

# reorder: default = by x axis name, we want order by male count
order = data["homeworld"].value_counts().index.tolist()

(
    pn.ggplot(data, pn.aes(x="factor(homeworld)", fill="factor(gender, ['male', 'female'])"))
    + pn.geom_bar(position=pn.position_dodge2(preserve = "single", padding = 0))
    + pn.scale_fill_manual({"male": pf.color.BLUE, "female": pf.color.RED})
    + pn.scale_x_discrete(limits=order)
    + pn.scale_y_continuous(expand = (0,0))
    + pn.labs(
        title = "Difference between males and females", 
        y = "Count", x = "Homeworld", 
        fill = 'Gender',
        caption = "There is a significant difference between the number of males and females on Naboo and Tatooine.",
    )
)


Since you use padding=0 anyway you can achieve your desired result by switching to position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"):
import plotnine as pn
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tidyverse/dplyr/refs/heads/main/data-raw/starwars.csv")

hw = data["homeworld"].value_counts().head(6)
data = data.merge(hw, left_on="homeworld", right_on="homeworld")

# Local data adjustments
data = data.dropna(subset=["sex"])

# reorder: default = by x axis name, we want order by male count
order = data["homeworld"].value_counts().index.tolist()

(
    pn.ggplot(data, pn.aes(x="factor(homeworld)", fill="factor(gender, ['masculine', 'feminine'])"))
    + pn.geom_bar(position=pn.position_dodge(preserve = "single"))
    + pn.scale_fill_manual({"masculine": "blue", "feminine": "red"})
    + pn.scale_x_discrete(limits=order)
    + pn.scale_y_continuous(expand = (0,0))
    + pn.labs(
        title = "Difference between males and females", 
        y = "Count", x = "Homeworld", 
        fill = 'Gender',
        caption = "There is a significant difference between the number of males and females on Naboo and Tatooine.",
    )
)


